# Character movement on irregular surface in Unity

Tags: unity, collision-detection, physics, character-controller

I'm currently implementing a system in Unity where I generate an approximation of a blood cell and treat it as a planetoid, as if you're playing Super Mario Galaxy, and you're running around the surface.  You can jump and get pulled to the surface and no matter where you are, you're pulled to the correct orientation.  I'm able to generate the shape and render it and I can implement a basic character controller, but the problem is that I'm not permitted to use colliders or rigidbodies for either the player or shape.  The only information I currently have to work with in my system is the collection of triangles, vertices, and the vertex normals.  How can I simulate this movement system that I've described?  I know how to simulate regular gravity (as if you're on a flat surface in a normal game) but I've got no clue what to do with the data I've generated.  I don't understand how I'd implement this without colliders.

Comment: Can you ray trace from the center of the blood cell to the feet of the player and determine where it intersects the blood cell mesh? That would give you where the lowest point the player's feet could be.